# Can $2^{M^N}+M^{N^2}$, where $M$ and $N$ are odd primes, never be a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

**Q**: Is number of the form $$\displaystyle 2^{M^N}+M^{N^2}$$ always composite for $M,N$ odd primes?

I observed that:

- If $M=N$ then this number is absolutely a composite, because it satisfies the identity $a+b \mid a^k+b^k$ if k is odd numbers.
- If $M \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then this number is always composite, because it divisible by $3$.

  I see that $2^{2c+1} \pmod 3=2$ for all natural numbers $c$, and $p^t \pmod 3=1$ if $p$ is a prime of type $1 \pmod 3$, then it is clear that $2^{M^N}+M^{N^2}$ divisible by $3$ if $M$ prime number of type $1 \pmod 3$.
- I have checked it exhaustively, and I always found it composites.

Comment: It's possible that it's always composite for no particular reason. The numbers grow so fast (and large numbers are prime less often) that the expected number of primes is finite; maybe there just aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason there are no primes of the form $2^{M^N}+M^{N^2}$ with $M,N$ odd primes, because what about if $M\equiv2\, (\text{mod}\, 3)$? I have checked numbers of that form, and I found first $3$ numbers with unknown status, and they are $2^{149^3}+149^{3^2}$, $2^{191^3}+191^{3^2}$, and $2^{29^5}+29^{5^2}$. These numbers have no prime factors up to $10^{20}$.

Comment: The three numbers $2^{149^3}+149^{3^2}$, $2^{191^3}+191^{3^2}$, and $2^{29^5}+29^{5^2}$ are still small enough that they can be PRP-tested (i.e. tested if they are a Fermat probable prime, cf. Fermat's little theorem) with software such as [PFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/). In the most likely case where they are composite, this will be definitively determined by that test. If they are prime, we will get an indication from PFGW, but a primality _proof_ is not computationally possible for these numbers. I have also added them to [factordb.com](http://factordb.com/).

Comment: I tested the two smallest ones, `2^(149^3)+149^(3^2) is composite: RES64: [A2BD93E165A25719]` respectively `2^(191^3)+191^(3^2) is composite: RES64: [83998DD74952A9AA]`. The last one would take more time. The chance of success for such a large number is tiny. I am not doing it.

Comment: Anyway, $2^{29^5}+29^{5^2}$ has [a relatively small factor](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000001554347241) so it is not needed to run a PRP test on this number (with over 6 million digits). So it was incorrect you claimed it had no factor up to $10^{20}$.